# How to remove string from string until a specefic character using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, cakephp

I want to remove the last parameter in the href of a specific  tag using jquery

for example replace `href="app/controller/action/05/04/2014"`

by `href="app/controller/action/05/04"`

Comment: try this:
    href=href.substring(0,href.lastIndexOf('/'));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the `String.lastIndexOf()` and `String.substring()` in this context to achieve what you want,

```
var xText ="app/controller/action/05/04/2014";
xText = xText.substring(0,xText.lastIndexOf('/'));
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/vdzG6/1/)

Comment: right one, though, slice is better option than substring always.

Comment: u forgot the ")" brace at end of 2nd line :)

Comment: @vivek_nk Yeah thanks, I just realised that while preparing a demo.. anyway thanks..

Comment: @R4mirezZ Glad to help.! consider this answer as accepted if you wish..! :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I can't , need more reps =/

Comment: @R4mirezZ You don't need reps to click on that tick mark..! :)

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I thought it was like voting ^^' , done !

Answer (score 0):

if you know which value you need to change ,than you can use replace:

```
var str = "app/controller/action/05/04/2014";
var res = str.replace("2014","04");
```

or else you can use array and change / update last value in array:

```
var str = "app/controller/action/05/04/2014";
var res = str.split("/");
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use a regular expression replace which will be the fastest, compared to substring/slice.

```
var hreftxt ="app/controller/action/05/04/2014";
hreftxt = hreftxt.replace(/\/[^\/]*$/,"");
```